# Average percentage overlap between two/more datasets

Tags: statistics, average, data-analysis

I am analyzing different schemes of mutual funds. Each scheme has many funds in its portfolio. I wanted to analyse the overlap (of funds) between these schemes. I can find the overlapping of scheme1 with scheme2 $(A \bigcap B) / A $, where $A$ is the no. of funds in scheme1 and $B$ is the no. of funds in scheme2. Is there a way I can find the average overlap between two schemes?

So, suppose these are my data(dataframes in pandas):

```
funds    Qty   Value   Asset%
fund_0   q_0   v_0      p_0
fund_1   q_1   v_1      p_1
fund_2   q_2   v_2      p_2
fund_3   q_3   v_3      p_3
fund_4   q_4   v_4      p_4
fund_5   q_5   v_5      p_5
fund_6   q_6   v_6      p_6
```

scheme2 looks like this:

```
funds    Qty    Value   Asset%
fund_0   q_0_2  v_0_2      p_0_2
fund_2   q_2_2  v_1_2      p_1_2
fund_5   q_5_2  v_6_2      p_6_2
fund_6   q_2    v_2         p_2
fund_7   q_3    v_3         p_3
fund_8   q_4    v_4         p_4
fund_9   q_5    v_5         p_5
fund_10  q_01   v_98        p_59
```

For this case, I will be having the common funds in these schemes as `fund_0,fund_2,fund_5 and fund_6` So I can find the overlap of each scheme with respect to other. Now I have some questions here:

1. Is there anything like average overlap, which would make sense in the real world?
2. Right now I am calculating the average overlap by using the number of common funds in each scheme. So for % overlap for scheme 1 above would be `100 * 4 / 7`, 7 being the total no. of funds in scheme 1. So is there a more meaningful metric for this?
3. What would be the overlap of portfolios or schemes mean in case of comparison between 3 or more schemes?

Comment: You could find the pairwise overlaps among all your funds, and take the average of that. Not sure if you want to weight some schemes more heavily than others on the basis of some criteria, but that's possible as well.